# iOS App crashes when deployed to device

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an app which I deploy to a physical device. The build succeeds and the App gets installed. But right after the launch image I get the error `failed to get the task for process 2284`.

When I quit XCode and launch the application manually on the device it runs without problems.

The XCode console does not give me much valuable information (See [Gist](https://gist.github.com/1dcb014a11950acc04cf))

[This gist](https://raw.github.com/gist/279d14d3b963c6537ca1/180f10db080bea793eb028d914a64f4ee20fadff/gistfile1.txt) shows what the console on the device recorded.

Comment: Which version of XCode are you using and have you installed any beta versions of XCode?

Comment: @marcus I am using XCode 4.0.2 and my device is an iPad2 with iOS 4.3.5

Comment: I guessed it would be a XCode 4.2 beta install which 'mixes' up the xcode tools, but as you have not/had not installed any betas, this is ruled out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out, that the problem occurs when I am debugging with a Distribution profile. When I create a non-Distribution provisioning profile for the App I can debug again.

Answer (score 0):

I got this a few times and after rebooting the iPhone (and maybe your Mac as well) everything worked like before the trouble started.

Comment: I have re-started both the Mac and the Device several times now, but to no avail...

Comment: I assume you already deleted the app from device and reinstalled it. What about launching the app from XCode without debugger? Can you start it without errors? If so, then something is wrong with debug settings. Some more ideas: Try target armv7. Use different compiler (LLVM-gcc vs. gcc 4.2)